# Find the values of $k$ such that $3$ is a zero of $f(x)= x^3+x^2+kx+1$

Tags: functions

I can't seem to solve this question. I don't understand where to start. How do I go about solving this question?

Comment: You need to solve for $k$ in $3^3+3^2+k(3)+1=0$.

Comment: Can you compute $f(3)$?  That is "where to start".

Comment: Are you familiar with the polynomial remainder theorem?

Comment: I tried putting 3 as my input but I get k = -37/3 and my textbook says the answer is k= 2 root(3) k= -2 root(3).

Comment: I cannot see why someone has voted to close this question. The OP has now shown that they have made a genuine attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct (assuming the question is written down correctly).

Since the book gives two values for $k$ this strongly indicates that the equation is not correct. I would expect to see a coefficient of $k^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did write down the equation correctly. There is probably just an error in the textbook (which has happened before).

Comment: You're welcome. As you will have noticed, questions might be closed unless you show some of the work you have tried on a problem so if you need help again make sure you show some work in the question and not just in the comments!